# Cannot read property 'set' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm using `fabric 3.4` to create a canvas element that gives `klass` object.

Say, I have variable `a` as

```
a = klass {lockScalingX: true}
```

I'm cloning this to `b` and updating b with some dictionary object

```
b = a.clone();
b.set({lockMovementY: true});
```

But this gives an error,

```
index.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

When I console log `a` and `b`. The b after the clone is `undefined`.

**How to clone `klass` object and use `set()` to update the values?**

**Or change fabric's `klass` to simple object?**

> Edit 2

Here is the screenshot of the console log.

[image]

It's an array and console has key 8, 9, 10 printing. I have expanded `8` to show the values contain in the key.

```
b[s] = a[s].clone();
console.log('a: ', a);        // This consoles the first code in the question.
console.log('b[s]: ', b[s]);  // This prints undefined

b[s].set({lockMovementY: true});  // This is giving error. Cannot read property set of undefined.
```

Comment: `a = klass {lockScalingX: true}` seems to be invalid javascript. What are you trying to do with this line?

Comment: Did you mean `a = new klass({lockScalingX: true})`?

Comment: `a` is a `new fabric.Canvas` object. When I console the `a` it gives that output where `klass` is grayed. I haven't written `klass` its the console output.

Comment: Could you please attach your code, not the console output?

Comment: Please check the Edit 2 section. It's not possible to post the whole code, as the calls are moving through many files. I have added a summary of the code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What you are assigning to `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by calling `toObject()` method of the fabric.

Earlier I was using fabric 1.x and was going through a project revamp. After upgrading fabric to 3.x, I started facing this issue. While creating a fabric canvas, object of type `klass` is returned.

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
```

In order to convert `klass` to object, I used `toObject()` method like

```
canvas.toObject()
```

which returns simple object and not the `klass` object.